# Delete last item of adapter doesn`t work

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, delete-row

i´ve already searched much on the internet but i didn´t found anything for my problem. I have my own adapter and when i long pressed the last item the app crashes but i don´t know why with all the other items it works fine.

Can you help me please?

Thats my code:

```
 holder.relativeLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            String click = finalHolder.txtTitle.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences s = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
            String last = s.getString("fav", "");
            if (!last.contains(";")) {
                    SharedPreferences so = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                    String lastpl = so.getString("fav", "");
                    lastpl = lastpl.replace(lastpl, "");
                    SharedPreferences sp8 = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp8.edit();
                    ed.putString("fav", lastpl);
                    ed.apply();
                    lv = lastpl;
                sprüche = new String[]{"Keine Favoriten vorhanden"};
                finalHolder.btn.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(transparent));
                }
                else {
                String[] hui;
                hui = last.split(";");
                if (!hui[0].equals(click)) {
                        SharedPreferences so = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                        String lastpl = so.getString("fav", "");
                        lastpl = lastpl.replace(";" + click, "");
                        SharedPreferences sp8 = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp8.edit();
                        ed.putString("fav", lastpl);
                        ed.apply();
                        lv = lastpl;
                        sprüche = lv.split(";");
                } else {
                    SharedPreferences so = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                    String lastpl = so.getString("fav", "");
                    lastpl = lastpl.replace(click+";", "");
                    SharedPreferences sp8 = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp8.edit();
                    ed.putString("fav", lastpl);
                    ed.apply();
                    lv = lastpl;
                    sprüche = lv.split(";");
                }
            }
                rowItems = new ArrayList<Liste3>();
                for (int ii = 0; ii < sprüche.length; ii++) {
                    Liste3 item = new Liste3(sprüche[ii]);
                    rowItems.add(item);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (click.equals(lastplay)) {
                    ui();
                    favorite = false;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

"last" are all items from the listview saved in one string.
"rowitems" is my own list.

Liste3:

```
public class Liste3 {
private String title;

public Liste3( String title) {
    this.title = title;

}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
}
```

Logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: de.kruemelopment.org.lustigewitze, PID: 9288
>                                                    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
>                                                         at de.kruemelopment.org.lustigewitze.k.getItem(Unknown Source)
>                                                         at de.kruemelopment.org.lustigewitze.k.getItemId(Unknown Source)
>                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChildInternal(AbsListView.java:4303)
>                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:4293)
>                                                         at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:6423)
>                                                        at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:6342)
>                                                         at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6296)
>                                                         at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6314)
>                                                        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:23721)
>                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Thats the complete adapter:

```
public class startadapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<Liste3> rowItems;


public startadapter(Context context, List<Liste3> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = items;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    Button btn;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.liste, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        holder.btn=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        holder.relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativ);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final Liste3 rowItem = (Liste3) getItem(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    if (!rowItem.getTitle().equals("Keine Favoriten vorhanden")) {
        holder.btn.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(ic_menu_share));
    }
    final ViewHolder finalHolder1 = holder;
    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (!rowItem.getTitle().equals("Keine Favoriten vorhanden")) {
               int position = 0;
               String he = finalHolder1.txtTitle.getText().toString();
               for (int in = 0; in < spr.length; in++) {
                   if (spr[in].contains(he)) {
                       position = in;
                   }
               }
               File k = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), he+".mp3");
               if (k.exists()) {
                   k.delete();
                   try {
                       k.createNewFile();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
               InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(sp[position]);
               FileOutputStream out = null;
               try {
                   out = new FileOutputStream(k);
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
               int read = 0;

               try {
                   while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                       out.write(buff, 0, read);
                   }
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } finally {
                   try {
                       in.close();
                       out.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

               }
               Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(k);
               Intent share=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               share.setType("audio/mp3");
               share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
               context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Witz teilen über..."));
            }
        }
    });
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String he = finalHolder.txtTitle.getText().toString();
            lastplay=he;
            favorite=true;
            u();
            SharedPreferences s = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
            String load = s.getString("fav", "");
            if (!load.isEmpty()) {
                int position = 0;
                for (int in = 0; in < spr.length; in++) {
                    if (spr[in].contains(he)) {
                        position = in;
                    }
                }
                if (i==1){
                    witz.stop();
                }
                witz = MediaPlayer.create(context, sp[position]);
                witz.start();
                i=1;
                witz.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        i=0;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            String click = finalHolder.txtTitle.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences s = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
            String last = s.getString("fav", "");
            if (!last.contains(";")) {
                    SharedPreferences so = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                    String lastpl = so.getString("fav", "");
                    lastpl = lastpl.replace(lastpl, "");
                    SharedPreferences sp8 = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp8.edit();
                    ed.putString("fav", lastpl);
                    ed.apply();
                    lv = lastpl;
                sprüche = new String[]{"Keine Favoriten vorhanden"};
                finalHolder.btn.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(transparent));
                }
                else {
                String[] hui;
                hui = last.split(";");
                    if (!hui[0].equals(click)) {
                        SharedPreferences so = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                        String lastpl = so.getString("fav", "");
                        lastpl = lastpl.replace(";" + click, "");
                        SharedPreferences sp8 = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp8.edit();
                        ed.putString("fav", lastpl);
                        ed.apply();
                        lv = lastpl;
                        sprüche = lv.split(";");
                    } else {
                        SharedPreferences so = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                        String lastpl = so.getString("fav", "");
                        lastpl = lastpl.replace(click + ";", "");
                        SharedPreferences sp8 = context.getSharedPreferences("Favs", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp8.edit();
                        ed.putString("fav", lastpl);
                        ed.apply();
                        lv = lastpl;
                        sprüche = lv.split(";");
                    }
                    rowItems = new ArrayList<Liste3>();
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < sprüche.length; ii++) {
                        Liste3 item = new Liste3(sprüche[ii]);
                        rowItems.add(item);
                    }
            }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (click.equals(lastplay)) {
                    ui();
                    favorite = false;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code of Liste3.java ?

Comment: Please share your code for adapter

Comment: what I think is that when you use the `replace` statement, it reduce the total number of ";" to zero or very close to zero. So after `split` function there is nothing to split with ";" so it'll produce an empty array. And when you tries to parse that array, which tries to access some elements of the array which does not exists leads to `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you plz share the logcat?  I beleive it will be index out of bound issue. But i need to see the log cat.if yes then replace your this piece of code

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < sprüche.length; ii++) {
                Liste3 item = new Liste3(sprüche[ii]);
                rowItems.add(item);
            }
```

With

```
   for (int ii = 0; ii <= sprüche.length-1; ii++) {
                Liste3 item = new Liste3(sprüche[ii]);
                rowItems.add(item);
            }
```

Comment: Yeah it says Indexoutofbounsexception Index:1 size:1

Comment: Is your exception generated in this piece of code?
   'for (int ii = 0; ii < sprüche.length; ii++) {
                    Liste3 item = new Liste3(sprüche[ii]);
                      rowItems.add(item);
                }'

Comment: Yes there it crashes

Comment: Use this code instead          for (int ii = 0; ii < sprüche.length-1; ii++) {
                    Liste3 item = new Liste3(sprüche[ii]);
                    rowItems.add(item);
                }

Comment: Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That makes that the selected one and the one over it will be deleted from ListView but  when i press the last item it still doesnt work

Comment: Share the Declaration of spruche and lv variables

Comment: static String[] sprüche;

Comment: static String lv="";

Comment: What is ui ()? . Where are you deleting the items?

Comment: Ui is only for an imageview which isn't importent 


I delete then on holder.relativeLayout.setOnlongClicklistener